# How to join a skype group via link programmatically?

Tags: c#, python, web, skype

I was wondering how you can join a skype group on the web (with a guest account, not a real account) programmatically. Using links like: (https://join.skype.com/XxXxXxXxXxXxXx) for example.

When you click the link it prompts you with a msgbox that asks you to either join with the desktop skype app (with an account) or continue as a guest < http://prntscr.com/d39jvx

If you continue as a guest, it asks for your guest name as shown here < prntscr.com/d39kkm

I want to be able to programmatically join as a guest preferably using C#.

Any ideas how?

Comment: I doubt you'll get an answer with code. You can figure this out though. Use TamperMonkey and chrome. TamperMonkey lets you intercept and analyze requests to the server. You can learn what is submitted on the two pages. Hopefully they don't encrypt it so you can just copy the requests and alter them.

Comment: Another way would be to use JS to programatically enter a name and click the button. Much easier. Depending on your needs you could inject this JS code in and have your program be a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Skype4Sharp](https://github.com/lin-e/Skype4Sharp) library on Github. This library contains all the functionality that's required to accomplish your goal.